# LibreOffice Writer (6.0.1.1): Lock it to export files as PDF instead EPUB

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, file-format, epub

I currently use LibreOffice Writer (6.0.1.1) and each time I export a document its default file extension is `.EPUB`. Thus, each time when I want the file to be exported as a PDF, I need to manually change the extension from `.EPUB` to an actual PDF.

How could I prevent that behavior by locking LO Writer somehow to automatically set file extension for the exported document as PDF?

---

<sub>Note: To export a document I do **File > Export > Save** (I then change the extension from .EPUB to PDF). I note this after someone asked about it in the comments.</sub>

Comment: @Dɑvïd If I use **File > Export > Save** menu and click on the Save button without changing the File Type, I get an EPUB.

Comment: @user68186 Funnily enough, when I use "**File > Export > Save** menu and click on the Save button without changing the File Type", I get `*.html`. Which is also the first choice listed in the drop-down when you click on `All Formats`. What's first in your list?

Comment: To me it's always only `.EPUB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to change the default file type of the **File > Export > Save** menu from EPUB to PDF. However, there are a few workarounds.

## 1. Use the **Export as PDF** icon

This is the simplest. The fourth icon on the top toolbar is **Export as PDF**.

[image]

This will directly take you to the Save file window with the PDF file type option selected. In some systems the icon may look a bit different.

[image]

## 2. Use the File > Export As Menu

Instead of using the **File > Export** menu, you can use the  **File > Export As > Export Directly as PDF** menu right below it.

[image]

This is the equivalent of clicking on the **Save As PDF** icon.

3. For the ultimate control...

If you want to change the PDF settings before you export the file as PDF, use the **File > Export As > Export as PDF** menu. this will take you to PDF options, where you can tweak your PDF file to be generated.

[image]

hope this helps